# How do I get my XSLT script to drill down 2 documents and compile the data into one HTML file?

Tags: xslt

I need to run an XSLT script on a ditamap XML file that drills down into 2 subfiles from the map to collect 2 pieces of data. The script isn't working and I'm stuck as to why. Any help would be most appreciated.

This is the script I have written so far but it isn't drilling down to the documents I need to pull the data from. I need to drill down into `maps/sec_s63_midterm_u1.ditamap` on the first ditamap and then `sec_s63_midterm_l1.ditamap` on the second ditamap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s9ml="http://www.standardnine.com/s9ml" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd xhtml s9ml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="maps" select="document(document(//mapref/@href)//mapref/@href)"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$maps">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2></h2>
                <table border="1">     
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>                
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="topicref">      
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@href, '/')[last()]"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="topicsubject/@keyref"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML file I need to run the script on:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd" []>
<bookmap>
    <frontmatter>
        <keydef keys="AssessmentInstruction" href="../assess_overviews/primary/s63_Midterm_Exam.dita"/>
    </frontmatter>
    
    <chapter href="../titles/sec_s63_title_u1.dita" locktitle="yes">
        <topicmeta>
            <navtitle>Unit 1: Definitions Under the Uniform Securities Act</navtitle>
        </topicmeta>
        <mapref href="maps/sec_s63_midterm_u1.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
    </chapter>

    <chapter href="../titles/sec_s63_title_u2.dita" locktitle="yes">
        <topicmeta>
            <navtitle>Unit 2: Regulation of Broker-Dealers and Their Agents Under the Uniform
                Securities Act</navtitle>
        </topicmeta>
        <mapref href="maps/sec_s63_midterm_u2.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
    </chapter>
</bookmap>
```

This is the second file the top level map links to (`maps/sec_s63_midterm_u1.ditamap`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

  <!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//KPE//DTD DITA KPE Map//EN" "kpe-map.dtd" []>
<map>
  <title>Unit 1: Definitions Under the Uniform Securities Act</title>
  <topicsubject format="ditamap" href="../../los/sec_s63_subjectscheme.ditamap"/>
    
  <topicref href="../../assess_overviews/primary/sec_s63_assessoverview_primary_l1.dita">
    <mapref href="sec_s63_midterm_l1.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
  </topicref>  
</map>
```

And this is the next linked XML file I need to pull the data from (`sec_s63_midterm_l1.ditamap`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

  <!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//KPE//DTD DITA KPE Map//EN" "kpe-map.dtd" []>
<map>
  <title><ph conref="../../titles/sec_s63_title_l1.dita#sec_s63_title_l1/topic_title"/></title>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_1.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_2.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref>
  
  <topicref href="../questions/sec_question_00260_3.dita">
    <topicsubject keyref="sec_s63_los_1"/>
  </topicref> 
</map>
```

Comment: Is that XSLT 1 or 2? Where does the prefix in `/xml:mapref` come from, I don't see it declared. Where is the element for `match="map"` if the (first) input document has `bookmap` as the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<xsl:variable name="atom-tags" select="document(document(//xml:mapref/@href)//xml:mapref/@href)"/>`. Assuming you somehow declare the right namespace for the prefix `xml`. Whether `xsl:for-each select="//topicref"` will select something also depends on whether the `topicref` elements are in no namespace or you set up `xpath-default-namespace` in XSLT 2/3 for their namespace.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I adjusted the XSLT script and I'm still not getting any data to output. My updated script is in the original post above. Any idea why I'm still not having any luck?

Comment: @pantherfan, as I said in a comment to your question, `xml:mapref` in your XSLT/XPath would just give an error about the prefix `xml` not being bound if the XSLT doesn't have any `xmlns:mapref="..."` namespace declaration.

Comment: @pantherfan, and whether `match="topicref"` can match anything is also not clear from your snippets, I guess the referenced DITA DTDs set up some namespace declaration attribute for all elements so your XSLT needs to use `xpath-default-namespace` for the relevant namespace(s).

Comment: I got it working. I added the script that's working to my original post. Thanks for all the help!!